# Xcode reporting errors about deleted classes?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Xcode sems to have real issues about deleting things. I deleted files GUI.h and GUI.m and clicked 'also send to trash'.

Nowhere in my program references this deleted class, and yet I'm getting an error:

"objc_class_name_GUI", referenced from:
objc_class_name_LevelLayer in LevelScene.o
Symbol(s) not found
Collect2: Id returned 1 exit status

What's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: Well... are you using the GUI class from LevelScene?

Comment: Sounds like references from object files. Clean should fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try cleaning your project (⇧⌘K) and building it again. You probably have some compiled object files which still reference those classes, and the compiler didn't notice that it should rebuild them. Also make sure that your LevelScene code doesn't still reference the deleted classes.